# Cargar Datatable con AJAX

Tags: ajax, datatables

*Hola, estoy implementando **DATATABLES** en mi aplicación Web.
Soy muy nuevo en este API, y se me ha presentado un problema:
Al intentar llenar mi Datatable con una llamada de AJAX, el Datatable solo se queda en "LOADING", y no se llena de ningún registro.*

**Anexo definición de mi Datatable en Código**

```
 var jsonResult;
 $('#datatableAnomalyReportsLPX').DataTable({
        fixedHeader: true,
        scrollX: true,
        searching: true,
        dom: 'Brtip',
        buttons: [
            'copyHtml5',
            'excelHtml5',
        ],
        pageLength: 6,
        ajax: {
            type: "POST",
            url: gContextPath + '/completeApi/AJAXGetReportsRegisters',
            data: {descriptionSelected: value},
            success: function(result) {
                jsonResult = JSON.parse(result);
                console.log(jsonResult)
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                console.log(error)
            }

        }
        data: jsonResult,
        columns: [
            {"data" : "lineAcronym"},
            {"data" : "parsedDateIssue"}
       ]
    });
```

Una de las dudas es la siguiente:

- La petición de AJAX la he configurado de la manera correcta? ya que, al imprimir **jsonResult** con un console.log(), si me está dando una respuesta correcta (el json Parseado).

Otros datos:
El servicio al que apunta en la petición AJAX, es un método de JAVA, que consulta a una Base de Datos y retorna un String, es en el Front donde el String lo parseo a JSON.

De antemano muchas gracias por la ayuda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He econtrado la solución:

1. Mi JSON desde la respuesta del Servidor estaba mal configurado. 
   - De acuerdo a la descripción en la página del API, el JSON que se retora, debe nombrarse de cierta manera en el Inicio, en mi caso, por defecto agregué el **KEY**, "data":

   { "data" :
   [
   { "key" : "value",
   "key2" : "value"
   } ...
   ]
   }

Después de formar de esta manera mi JSON, definí de la siguiente manera mi Datatable:

```
$('#datatableAnomalyReports').DataTable({
            processing: true,
            ajax: {
                type: "POST",
                url: gContextPath + '/anomalyReports/anomalyReportsController/AJAXGetAnomalyReportsRegisters',
                data: {someKey: someValue}
            },
            columns: [
                {"data" : "key"},
                {"data" : "key2"}
            ]
        });
```

En la definición del Datatable, no hace falta referenciar la opción **data**, ya que, por defecto en tomará ese key.
Si se pone otro, solo en la sección del AJAX, es necesario poner **dataSrc = 'keyName'**, sustituyendo **keyName** por el nombre del key en el JSON.

Espero sirva para alguien. (: